# FSC: Error FS2024: Static linking may not use assembly that targets different profile

Tags: dll, visual-studio-2013, f#

F# is my first programming language. I use MS Visual Studio 2013, .NET Framework 4.5. For my personal coding project, these are the references I have included:

> - FSharp.Data.TypeProviders
> - Microsoft.Experimental.Collections
> - Newtonsoft.Json
> - System
> - System.Data
> - System.Data.Linq
> - System.Runtime.Serialization
> - System.Xml

I received the error message mentioned in the title of this post. I tried the solution mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25176846/3559686), but I could not install the latest Visual F# Tools Build, apparently because "A certificate chain could not be built to a trusted root authority". So I tried to download the appropriate security update, as recommended on [this Microsoft Support page](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/dn265983.aspx), but a pop-up appeared with this message: "The update is not applicable to your computer".

After my failure to download the latest Visual F# Tools Build, I proceeded to remove all of my references, and then added them back again. After re-adding each reference, I re-built my solution to check whether I would get an error message informing me that Error FS2024 had occurred. I received the following error message after re-adding System.Data.Linq:

> warning MSB3277: Found conflicts between different versions of the
>   same dependent assembly that could not be resolved.

I checked all of my references individually, and discovered that all of them referenced the same versions of common dependent assemblies. I have absolutely no idea what prompted that warning.

I am currently at my wits' end, and I would appreciate any help I can get.

EDIT:

I have set the MSBuild project output verbosity to "Detailed". I expected to see error messages similar to the example on [this page](https://michaelmairegger.wordpress.com/2014/11/10/found-conflicts-between-different-versions-of-the-same-dependent-assembly/), but there were none.

EDIT:

I apologize for the wall of text below. I have copied and pasted the build output:

> ------ Build started: Project: FighterAnalysis, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------ Target "_CheckForInvalidConfigurationAndPlatform" in
>   file "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets" from
>   project "G:\Back-up\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\FighterAnalysis\FighterAnalysis\FighterAnalysis.fsproj"
>   (entry point):    Task "Message"  Task "Message" Target "BeforeBuild" in
>   file "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets" from
>   project "G:\Back-up\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\FighterAnalysis\FighterAnalysis\FighterAnalysis.fsproj"
>   (target "Build" depends on it): Target "BuildOnlySettings" in file
>   "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets" from
>   project "G:\Back-up\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\FighterAnalysis\FighterAnalysis\FighterAnalysis.fsproj"
>   (target "CoreBuild" depends on it): Target "GetFrameworkPaths" in file
>   "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.NetFramework.CurrentVersion.targets"
>   from project "G:\Back-up\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\FighterAnalysis\FighterAnalysis\FighterAnalysis.fsproj"
>   (target "PrepareForBuild" depends on it): Target
>   "GetReferenceAssemblyPaths" in file "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets" from
>   project "G:\Back-up\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\FighterAnalysis\FighterAnalysis\FighterAnalysis.fsproj"
>   (target "PrepareForBuild" depends on it):     Task
>   "GetReferenceAssemblyPaths" Target "PrepareForBuild" in file
>   "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets" from
>   project "G:\Back-up\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\FighterAnalysis\FighterAnalysis\FighterAnalysis.fsproj"
>   (target "CoreBuild" depends on it):   Task "FindAppConfigFile"    Task
>   "MakeDir" Target "BeforeResolveReferences" in file "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets" from
>   project "G:\Back-up\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\FighterAnalysis\FighterAnalysis\FighterAnalysis.fsproj"
>   (target "ResolveReferences" depends on it): Target
>   "AssignProjectConfiguration" in file "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets" from
>   project "G:\Back-up\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\FighterAnalysis\FighterAnalysis\FighterAnalysis.fsproj"
>   (target "ResolveReferences" depends on it):   Task
>   "AssignProjectConfiguration" Target
>   "_SplitProjectReferencesByFileExistence" in file "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets" from
>   project "G:\Back-up\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\FighterAnalysis\FighterAnalysis\FighterAnalysis.fsproj"
>   (target "ResolveProjectReferences" depends on it): Target
>   "ResolveProjectReferences" in file "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets" from
>   project "G:\Back-up\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\FighterAnalysis\FighterAnalysis\FighterAnalysis.fsproj"
>   (target "ResolveReferences" depends on it): Target
>   "GetInstalledSDKLocations" in file "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets" from
>   project "G:\Back-up\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\FighterAnalysis\FighterAnalysis\FighterAnalysis.fsproj"
>   (target "ResolveSDKReferences" depends on it): Target
>   "ResolveSDKReferences" in file "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets" from
>   project "G:\Back-up\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\FighterAnalysis\FighterAnalysis\FighterAnalysis.fsproj"
>   (target "ResolveAssemblyReferences" depends on it): Target
>   "ExpandSDKReferences" in file "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets" from
>   project "G:\Back-up\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\FighterAnalysis\FighterAnalysis\FighterAnalysis.fsproj"
>   (target "ResolveAssemblyReferences" depends on it): Target
>   "ResolveAssemblyReferences" in file "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets" from
>   project "G:\Back-up\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\FighterAnalysis\FighterAnalysis\FighterAnalysis.fsproj"
>   (target "ResolveReferences" depends on it):   Task
>   "ResolveAssemblyReference" Target "GenerateBindingRedirects" in file
>   "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets" from
>   project "G:\Back-up\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\FighterAnalysis\FighterAnalysis\FighterAnalysis.fsproj"
>   (target "ResolveReferences" depends on it):   Task
>   "GenerateBindingRedirects"        No suggested binding redirects from
>   ResolveAssemblyReferences. Target "AfterResolveReferences" in file
>   "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets" from
>   project "G:\Back-up\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\FighterAnalysis\FighterAnalysis\FighterAnalysis.fsproj"
>   (target "ResolveReferences" depends on it): Target
>   "ImplicitlyExpandDesignTimeFacades" in file "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.NetFramework.CurrentVersion.targets"
>   from project "G:\Back-up\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\FighterAnalysis\FighterAnalysis\FighterAnalysis.fsproj"
>   (target "ResolveReferences" depends on it):   Task "Message" Target
>   "ResolveReferences" in file "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets" from
>   project "G:\Back-up\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\FighterAnalysis\FighterAnalysis\FighterAnalysis.fsproj"
>   (target "CoreBuild" depends on it): Target "ValidationExtension" in
>   file
>   "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.WorkflowBuildExtensions.targets"
>   from project "G:\Back-up\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\FighterAnalysis\FighterAnalysis\FighterAnalysis.fsproj"
>   (target "PrepareResources" depends on it): Target
>   "ExpressionBuildExtension" in file
>   "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.WorkflowBuildExtensions.targets"
>   from project "G:\Back-up\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\FighterAnalysis\FighterAnalysis\FighterAnalysis.fsproj"
>   (target "PrepareResources" depends on it): Target
>   "AfterMarkupCompilePass1" in file
>   "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.WinFx.targets"
>   from project "G:\Back-up\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\FighterAnalysis\FighterAnalysis\FighterAnalysis.fsproj"
>   (target "PrepareResources" depends on it): Target "FileClassification"
>   in file
>   "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.WinFx.targets"
>   from project "G:\Back-up\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\FighterAnalysis\FighterAnalysis\FighterAnalysis.fsproj"
>   (target "PrepareResources" depends on it): Target "AssignTargetPaths"
>   in file "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets" from
>   project "G:\Back-up\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\FighterAnalysis\FighterAnalysis\FighterAnalysis.fsproj"
>   (target "PrepareResourceNames" depends on it):    Task
>   "AssignTargetPath"    Task "AssignTargetPath"     Task "AssignTargetPath"
>     Task "AssignTargetPath" Target "SplitResourcesByCulture" in file
>   "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets" from
>   project "G:\Back-up\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\FighterAnalysis\FighterAnalysis\FighterAnalysis.fsproj"
>   (target "PrepareResourceNames" depends on it):    Task "AssignCulture"
>   Target "CreateCustomManifestResourceNames" in file "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets" from
>   project "G:\Back-up\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\FighterAnalysis\FighterAnalysis\FighterAnalysis.fsproj"
>   (target "PrepareResourceNames" depends on it): Target
>   "PrepareResourceNames" in file "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets" from
>   project "G:\Back-up\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\FighterAnalysis\FighterAnalysis\FighterAnalysis.fsproj"
>   (target "PrepareResources" depends on it): Target "BeforeResGen" in
>   file "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets" from
>   project "G:\Back-up\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\FighterAnalysis\FighterAnalysis\FighterAnalysis.fsproj"
>   (target "ResGen" depends on it): Target "CoreResGen" in file
>   "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets" from
>   project "G:\Back-up\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\FighterAnalysis\FighterAnalysis\FighterAnalysis.fsproj"
>   (target "ResGen" depends on it): Target "AfterResGen" in file
>   "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets" from
>   project "G:\Back-up\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\FighterAnalysis\FighterAnalysis\FighterAnalysis.fsproj"
>   (target "ResGen" depends on it): Target "ResGen" in file "C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets"
>   from project "G:\Back-up\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\FighterAnalysis\FighterAnalysis\FighterAnalysis.fsproj"
>   (target "PrepareResources" depends on it): Target "PrepareRdlFiles" in
>   file "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\ReportingServices\Microsoft.ReportingServices.targets"
>   from project "G:\Back-up\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\FighterAnalysis\FighterAnalysis\FighterAnalysis.fsproj"
>   (target "CompileRdlFiles" depends on it): Target "CompileRdlFiles" in
>   file "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\ReportingServices\Microsoft.ReportingServices.targets"
>   from project "G:\Back-up\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\FighterAnalysis\FighterAnalysis\FighterAnalysis.fsproj"
>   (target "PrepareResources" depends on it): Target "PrepareResources"
>   in file "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets" from
>   project "G:\Back-up\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\FighterAnalysis\FighterAnalysis\FighterAnalysis.fsproj"
>   (target "CoreBuild" depends on it): Target
>   "_SetEmbeddedWin32ManifestProperties" in file "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets" from
>   project "G:\Back-up\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\FighterAnalysis\FighterAnalysis\FighterAnalysis.fsproj"
>   (target "SetWin32ManifestProperties" depends on it):  Task
>   "GetFrameworkPath" Target "SetWin32ManifestProperties" in file
>   "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets" from
>   project "G:\Back-up\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\FighterAnalysis\FighterAnalysis\FighterAnalysis.fsproj"
>   (target "Compile" depends on it): Target "_GenerateCompileInputs" in
>   file "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets" from
>   project "G:\Back-up\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\FighterAnalysis\FighterAnalysis\FighterAnalysis.fsproj"
>   (target "Compile" depends on it): Target
>   "GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute" in file "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\F#\3.1\Framework\v4.0\Microsoft.FSharp.Targets"
>   from project "G:\Back-up\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\FighterAnalysis\FighterAnalysis\FighterAnalysis.fsproj"
>   (target "BeforeCompile" depends on it):   Skipping target
>   "GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute" because all output files are
>   up-to-date with respect to the input files. Target "BeforeCompile" in
>   file "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets" from
>   project "G:\Back-up\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\FighterAnalysis\FighterAnalysis\FighterAnalysis.fsproj"
>   (target "Compile" depends on it): Target
>   "DesignTimeXamlMarkupCompilation" in file
>   "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Xaml.targets"
>   from project "G:\Back-up\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\FighterAnalysis\FighterAnalysis\FighterAnalysis.fsproj"
>   (target "CoreCompile" depends on it): Target
>   "DesignTimeMarkupCompilation" in file
>   "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.WinFx.targets"
>   from project "G:\Back-up\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\FighterAnalysis\FighterAnalysis\FighterAnalysis.fsproj"
>   (target "CoreCompile" depends on it): Target "CoreCompile" in file
>   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   SDKs\F#\3.1\Framework\v4.0\Microsoft.FSharp.Targets" from project
>   "G:\Back-up\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\FighterAnalysis\FighterAnalysis\FighterAnalysis.fsproj"
>   (target "Compile" depends on it):     Task "Fsc"      C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\F#\3.1\Framework\v4.0\fsc.exe
>   -o:obj\Debug\FighterAnalysis.exe -g --debug:full --noframework --define:DEBUG --define:TRACE --doc:bin\Debug\ConsoleApplication8.XML --optimize- --tailcalls- --platform:anycpu32bitpreferred -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\FSharp.NETFramework\v4.0\4.3.0.0\FSharp.Core.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\FSharp.NETFramework\v4.0\4.3.0.0\Type
>   Providers\FSharp.Data.TypeProviders.dll" -r:"G:\Back-up\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\FighterAnalysis\packages\Microsoft.Experimental.Collections.1.0.3-alpha\lib\portable-net45+win8+wp8\Microsoft.Experimental.Collections.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\SDK\Assemblies\Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll"
>   -r:G:\Downloads\Json60r8\Bin\Net40\Newtonsoft.Json.dll -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Core.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Data.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Data.Linq.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\System.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Xml.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Xml.Linq.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades\System.Collections.Concurrent.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades\System.Collections.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades\System.ComponentModel.Annotations.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades\System.ComponentModel.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades\System.ComponentModel.EventBasedAsync.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades\System.Diagnostics.Contracts.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades\System.Diagnostics.Debug.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades\System.Diagnostics.Tools.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades\System.Diagnostics.Tracing.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades\System.Dynamic.Runtime.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades\System.Globalization.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades\System.IO.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades\System.Linq.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades\System.Linq.Expressions.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades\System.Linq.Parallel.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades\System.Linq.Queryable.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades\System.Net.NetworkInformation.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades\System.Net.Primitives.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades\System.Net.Requests.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades\System.ObjectModel.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades\System.Reflection.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades\System.Reflection.Emit.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades\System.Reflection.Emit.ILGeneration.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades\System.Reflection.Emit.Lightweight.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades\System.Reflection.Extensions.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades\System.Reflection.Primitives.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades\System.Resources.ResourceManager.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades\System.Runtime.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades\System.Runtime.Extensions.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades\System.Runtime.InteropServices.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades\System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades\System.Runtime.Numerics.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades\System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades\System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades\System.Runtime.Serialization.Xml.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades\System.Security.Principal.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades\System.ServiceModel.Duplex.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades\System.ServiceModel.Http.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades\System.ServiceModel.NetTcp.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades\System.ServiceModel.Primitives.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades\System.ServiceModel.Security.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades\System.Text.Encoding.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades\System.Text.Encoding.Extensions.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades\System.Text.RegularExpressions.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades\System.Threading.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades\System.Threading.Tasks.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades\System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades\System.Xml.ReaderWriter.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades\System.Xml.XDocument.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades\System.Xml.XmlSerializer.dll"
>   --target:exe --warn:3 --warnaserror:76 --vserrors --validate-type-providers --LCID:1033 --utf8output --fullpaths --flaterrors --subsystemversion:6.00 --highentropyva+ --sqmsessionguid:d24010b1-a544-43f6-9d1b-7c36097d4bb9 "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.AssemblyAttributes.fs"
>   ConvertToAndFromDotNetTypes.fs Fighter.fs Fight.fs FightUpdated.fs
>   HtmlParsing.fs JsonMethods.fs UrlInfo.fs GetFighterInfo.fs
>   Download1.fs Download2.fs CompareFighters.fs Program.fs  FSC: error
>   FS2024: Static linking may not use assembly that targets different
>   profile. Target "_CheckForCompileOutputs" in file "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets" from
>   project "G:\Back-up\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\FighterAnalysis\FighterAnalysis\FighterAnalysis.fsproj"
>   (target "_CleanGetCurrentAndPriorFileWrites" depends on it): Target
>   "_CleanGetCurrentAndPriorFileWrites" in file "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets" from
>   project "G:\Back-up\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\FighterAnalysis\FighterAnalysis\FighterAnalysis.fsproj"
>   (target "_CleanRecordFileWrites" depends on it):  Task
>   "ReadLinesFromFile"   Task "ConvertToAbsolutePath"    Task
>   "FindUnderPath"   Task "FindUnderPath"    Task "FindUnderPath"    Task
>   "RemoveDuplicates" Target "_CleanRecordFileWrites" in file "C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets"
>   from project "G:\Back-up\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\FighterAnalysis\FighterAnalysis\FighterAnalysis.fsproj"
>   (target "CoreBuild" depends on it):   Task "RemoveDuplicates"     Task
>   "MakeDir"     Task "WriteLinesToFile" Done building project
>   "FighterAnalysis.fsproj" -- FAILED.

Comment: This is a pretty difficult question to answer in this format.  I suggest finding a chat room or some such in which to ask for assistance.

Comment: @mydogisbox, which chat room would you recommend?

Comment: http://fpchat.com/ is one or you can ask in the SO F# chat room.

Comment: Some of the libraries appear to be targeting .NET 4.0 and some 4.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the problem by creating a new project, migrating all my source files over and re-installing all the DLLs I need. After doing so, I have no trouble whatsoever building my project. I think Carsten (who wrote the first comment to [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30410855/f-is-profile-47-required-for-microsoft-fsharp-data-typeproviders/30411434#30411434)) is correct in saying that the versions somehow became messed up in the original solution files.